# How to access object inside Foreach?

Tags: php

My array looks like this:

```
Array
(
[id] => 196011470503479_873596956078257
[message] => #Dabur India Ltd has been ranked amongst India's Super 50 Companies by Forbes India. The annual list ranks companies that generate high returns for investors, grow their Revenues strongly and deploy funds efficiently.
[created_time] => DateTime Object
    (
        [date] => 2016-07-29 04:00:01.000000
        [timezone_type] => 1
        [timezone] => +00:00
    )

[shares] => Array
    (
        [count] => 26
    )
```

PHP Code

```
</tbody>
    <?php
        $i = 1;
        foreach($arr['posts'] as $poInd=>$poVal){
            echo "
                <tr>
                    <td>".$i."</td>
                    <td>".$poVal['id']."</td>
                    <td>".$poVal['name']."</td>
                    <td>".$poVal['message']."</td>
                    <td>".($poVal['created_time']->date)."</td>
                    <td>".$poVal['shares']['count']."</td>
                    <td>".count($poVal['likes'])."</td>
                    <td>".count($poVal['comments'])."</td>
                </tr>
            ";
            $i++;
        }
    ?>
</tbody>
```

My output is 
[image]
In my table the 5th column is `created_time`, in my array `created_time` index contains a `DateTime` object. So how do you get the date from a `DateTime` object inside the `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`created_time` is a  `DateTime` object, so you should use it i.e. with:

```
$poVal['created_time']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a datetime object in your array `$poVal['created_time']`. So Use [format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) with datetimeobject

`$poVal['created_time']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Comment: How is this answer any different from `@haz`??